# Which program runs first? Is it Boot Loader or Boot Manager?

Tags: boot, operating-systems, bootloader, boot-manager

I have read many articles regarding Boot Loader and Boot Manager over the internet. From that knowledge, what I conclude is:

**Boot Manager** is a program which basically decides what operating system is to be loaded into the machine. It is sort of an interface between operating system and firmware.

**Boot Loader** is the program which actually loads the Operating System kernel into the main memory of system.

So technically, Boot Manager should run prior to the Boot Loader as it is the one to decide the operating system to be loaded.

But when I came across [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/bootloader#:%7E:text=Open%2DSource%20Software&text=Whenever%20a%20computing%20system%20is,%2C%20RedBoot%2C%20Yaboot%2C%20etc.) site, it says Boot Loader is the first to load.

Can anyone take away my confusion? Or what the above site has mentioned is specific to a particular platform?

Answer (score 2):

The first lines of that web page that you cite are:

> Bootloader
>
> The bootloader program demonstrates how to jump from one program to the start of another.
>
> From: The Designer's Guide to the ***Cortex-m*** Processor Family, 2013

The article you cite is intended to describe Cortex-M processors, which is typically integrated into a "microcontroller", and is not describing PCs.

Cortex-M processors are intended for use in embedded systems, which are much less sophisticated than PCs or systems using Cortex-A (which has an MMU for virtual memory). The typical Cortex-M embedded system could simply use a micro-kernel and a dedicated application program; there is no OS or "*Boot Manager*". A Cortex-M embedded system could use XIP (execute in place) flash memory, and not even require a boot program to load anything into memory!

Bottom line: you're citing an inappropriate reference document.

---

Your description of a "*Boot Manager*" as "*a program which basically decides what operating system is to be loaded into the machine*" would typically be a program that was installed on a mass storage device (e.g. an HDD or SSD) designated as the boot drive (in the PC BIOS?).  Such a program can only be executed after a bootloader copied that "*Boot Manager*" program into main memory so that it can be executed.

Note that a computer system typically employs a multi-stage boot sequence. In other words, there is not just one "*boot loader*", but rather a succession of boot programs. A boot program could execute completely silent (i.e. not display any console messages), or could present a user interface, e.g. U-Boot's command line or a "*Boot Manager's*" menu.

Comment: ` Such a program can only be executed after a bootloader copied that "Boot Manager" program into main memory so that it can be executed.` Then who copied the bootloader?

Comment: That depends on the processor architecture & vendor. Beware that you're referring to programs that probably execute in main memory, which is typically some type of dynamic RAM. DRAM needs a controller that requires initialization before that memory can be used (e.g. configure the refresh). This implies that there is initialization code that is executing from some other memory that is not DRAM, typically ROM, some times SRAM. See https://superuser.com/questions/1066095/assuming-you-cant-directly-boot-into-a-linux-system-how-do-you-make-the-bootst/1066124#1066124

Comment: Yeah apparently on ARM boards, all those early firmware blobs are coined bootloaders as well, while they are at least from some perspectives similar to BIOS on x86/PC (initialize stuff and have some static boot device order or so). I still wonder if "boot manager" is a thing on them though (except when you introduce UEFI firmware to them), and I really don't recall the term being used before UEFI appeared (even "Windows Boot Manager" was born with both BIOS and UEFI variants, IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

**For a stu... troll question a troll answer**

I don't want to bear a bad news, but this question seems "tiny bit wrong", or **completely nonsensical** rather, at least without proper *context*.

Context being, as was already asked in other answers, what CPU and what kind of machine architecture and what kind of platform are you asking about?

If you are asking generally, the answer is: **Only firmware is the first program to ever run and that's it!** Case is closed.

The problem of your question is, that computer bootstrap processes are highly convoluted messes, depending lot on a hardware, firmware and a system layouts. These layouts can be vary wildly and can be almost completely different among platforms, architectures and even between the two boards within the same platform.

As they say - devil is in the details here.

---

**General answer**

Technically, all CPUs have hardcoded address to which they jump to every time, when their reset pin gets triggered, or when they boot up - and that is all there is to it.

And initially there was nothing there, on that address, only zeroes. I think most CPUs end up in reset loop in that case, or end up triple-faulting (or something).

On ancient computers like, [Altair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_8800) and similar, you had the ability to control CPU (and through it, the memory) with switches and blinkenlights on the front panel, and while very crude, this mechanism actually allowed you to "input" a "program" (in actual bits, by means of little on/off switches) on that RESET address.

And that is how you input your very rudimentary "loader": a program, only a few instructions long. This "hand input" code was basically a very simple loop, that would load determined number of bytes (letters) from teletype paper tape as a program code and jump to the start of it. This start chunk of tape would actually contain yet another "program", a more sophisticated one, that would then load a rest of the payload code from the paper tape and jump to start of that again and that would be the code that would actually power the computer. In Altair's case this code was often a BASIC interpreter, for example.

So you put CPU into special entry mode with a switch, and then by flipping dozens of other switches on the panel in several successions back forth (around few minutes) you input that primordial first load loop program. You loaded the tape into teletype and reset the CPU - and if you did everything right, the teletype would start churning the tape and load the payload. Some dozens minutes later you would be welcomed by command prompt.

On modern platforms CPU and memory circuitry is setup in such a away, that firmware ROM chip maps to that CPU's "reset" address. Any code that is stored there can be considered "firmware", and will get executed automagically each time when CPU is reset.

---

**IBM PC boot process**

If you were asking about original IBM PC: that RESET memory area is where so called BIOS was "located". This memory mapping was usually setup in a kind of peculiar way, but those were implementation details.

The BIOS code was supposed to initialize the rest of the machine: mainly memory controllers, input/output systems (serial lines, parallel lines, keyboard), graphics system, and most importantly disk controller.

The BIOS ROM memory was certainly very tight back then, so once all the listed got setup, there was not much room for anything else and BIOS simply loaded first sector of a first floppy (or a first hard disk later) and jumped straight to it's start, blindly ... and that was it.

MS-DOS, the most used OS of that time, mandates a partition table there, so there was slight conflict of interest, between BIOS and OS. Thus all the boot sectors of that era share some part of it's size with so called "loader" code and rest is reserved to actual partition data. After some time this 0th sector got special name: MBR - a Master Boot Record.

Unfortunately BIOS loaded really only a single - first/zeroth - sector from the disk and that was that, and so this "stage1" code, as it is often called, was not enough to load a rest of the OS. If we subtract the need for partition table data, there is roughly only ~450-220 bytes of space for the loading code in historical 512 byte sector from that era.

That size was simply not enough to implement FAT table parser, load root directory and locate actual DOS kernel there. So this code, usually, concerned itself only with loading the rest of the sectors after the MBR, usually called the first "track". This was the code that existed in "unaccounted for in-between space" after MBR, but before the start of the first partition. This was the actual kernel "locator"/loader code. It had to implement partition data parsing, active partition identificator, FAT parser, and FAT file loader. It then located the IO.SYS (DOS all-driver "pack") which would then load rest of the DOS kernel (MSDOS.SYS or what have you).

I hope you are already spotting analogies with Altair tape.

---

**Wild Boot Manager appears**

As operating systems got more complex, the in-between "loader disk area" become to small to hold all the code to load an OS itself. I guess this is the point where in IBM PCs the concept of **Boot Manager** and **Boot Loader** got introduced.

On IBM PC **Boot manager** used to be small, file-less program, you could install into the "in-between" area of the disk that would allow you to defer loading process through "OS selection menu".

More famous one was so called [Ranish Partition Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranish_Partition_Manager), but there were more.

---

**"Booter" revolution**

As we said, at some point in time (circa 2000) a storage space became a problem (as a size in-between the MBR and partition sectors was not enough for more advanced functionality), so this lead to a wild west time, where all the "*bootloaders*" stopped to fit into the "in-between space".

Thus most bootloaders became 3 stage entities: MBR is stage 1, in-between space part is stage 2, filesystem based part is stage 3. (Be careful these are *real* stages invented by me, not the "industry" stages, that bootloader writers themselves refer to - in their eyes "my" stage 3 is "their" stage 2 - in fact any bootstrapping systems will have as many bootstrapping stages as it will need to boot any OS fully).

What does my stage 3 means? It means that bootloaders now got so big that it made no sense to keep then in "file-less" disk area. Code in in-between file-less disk area is still needed, but it is playing more of a role of an old MS-DOS IO.SYS (multi-driver-pack file) - a role of a disk and core filesystem driver - that is used to load actual bootloader as a file. Yeah if you consider this design funny - it is.

So, these new bootloaders, they all grew a core filesystem driver (usually they all always understand at least one primary filesystem (often FAT filesystem)) and now know how to load a rest of a bootloader as a files from the "bootloader partition" itself. Getting confusing? It is - I know.

By this time you can see a bootloader as kind of "micro operating system" in itself, on level of complexity roughly somewhere between MS-DOS and Win 9x.

Major boot loaders of this era are (ordedered by "retardedness" from less retarded to more retarded):

- [SYSLINUX](https://www.syslinux.org/old/index.php) (and family: ISOLINUX, PXELINUX etc)
- [XOSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOSL) - eXtended Operating System Loader
- [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) - Grand unified bootloader - name tells it all
- [Windows BOOTMGR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting_process_of_Windows_NT_since_Vista) - Windows BootManager

Get ready, because from now on it will only get more confusing going forward.

---

**Everybody boots with everybody**

What changed, that it lead to this filesystem based bootloader development?

Well, the computers and OSes became more complex.

Bootloaders now needed to know more filesystems and many OS kernels got much, much bigger than 64 kilobytes and are modularized and unified.

Bootloader's filesystem drivers got more complex as a result: it must able to load multi-megabyte kernel file, it's modules, all which can be using all the features of the hosting storage filesystem - ie it might be a very big file on a very big partition (several terabytes big) and this kernel file can be, for example heavily fragmented (etc.).

So said differently: now the bootloader filesystem driver does not need just to be able to parse the a simple FAT (or ETX2) root directory structure, it must be able to walk all the kernel file fragments (of which there could be thousands) which might be dispersed (because of filesystem fragmentation) multiple terabytes apart and assemble them into single chunk of OS kernel in the computer's memory. It's not a simple "baby" filesystem driver anymore. It does not have to be as complex as "real" OS filesystems driver yet (because bootloaders only read files), but it's not simple anymore.

Thus it was now impossible to include all the loader functionality into a single giant loader binary that would fit into one "track" in-between the start of a disk and first partition data anymore. Disks don't even have tracks anymore (in a traditional disk track sense).

As such, it made more sense to split the bootloader into smaller chunks - so called files: a core program part and a "plugins" parts (so-called modules, or in normal OS speak: DLLs) and store them somewhere. And what better ways to store files than in a filesystem partition. And we get to reuse a driver used for loading kernel to load bootloader and it's parts itself.

Most of these loaders now "talk" at least a few filesystems (unordered):

- SYSLINUX: EXT2, FAT, ISO
- Windows loader: FAT, NTFS
- GRUB: EXT2, FAT, BTRFS, ZFS

So loader now has dlls (and drivers) itself. What else we can use this modularity for?

GRUB can now configure serial lines (for example for GPU-less computers).

Almost all these bootloaders can now draw useless pretty pictures (so called loading screens) for casuals to look at, while booting doing nothing useful besides showing throbber animation. Why such condescending tone? You have to understand: if you want pictures, you need graphics programming - which is special subclass of "normal" programming. You need graphics routines, but that is not enough. You need framebuffer driver, graphics hardware drivers etc. I hope you are starting to get a point. So these graphics stack parts are all special dlls and drivers inside a bootloader partition.

Almost all of these bootloaders can now also load so called [MULTIBOOT](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot2/multiboot.html) kernels. Which are almost all the kernels of all the OSes by now (not sure about Microsoft products though).

The point is, that any MULTIBOOT compliant bootloader can load any MULTIBOOT compliant kernel (of any OS).

More over MULTIBOOT compliant bootloaders are MULTIBOOT compliant themselves, so you can effortlessly create "chains" of bootloaders ie: SYSLINUX bootloader loading GRUB bootloader loading Windows Bootloader.

This might look silly but is actually very useful feature used to make zillions of rescue CDs and network boot setups.

Next, all of these bootloaders now have boot menu dll modules, loaded and configured from the bootloader partition like everything else. These menu plugins come both in textual and graphical flavor, so now each bootloader can act as a **Boot Manager** themselves! I warned you this will be getting confusing quickly.

Finally, as the bootloader now understand files - it can be configured directly by editing files, which is much more convenient for the user.

Unless you are using GRUB and Windows Bootloader, of course, which are ridiculed for their convoluted over-complexity even in OS engineering circles. Hint: these two bootloaders truly are retarded.

---

**Brand New world of UEFI: One ring to rule them all**

Previous part of history introduced lot of good things (but also lot of bad: like insane obesity of GRUB) for the user.

In fact and the most importantly: it brought insane amount of freedom to the user, especially on how to setup a system boot (if you can dig all the details that is, which seem to be skill, that is evaporating quicker and quicker every year).

And in game of thrones world of modern for profit corporations, there is no worse thing as absolute freedom of the user.

All the innovation, we saw so far, was caused by single fact: that the BIOS could load only a single sector from disk to boot.

This seemingly severe limitation lead to creation of sprawling niche ecosystem of opensource boot solutions. But this was to be no more.

The boot movement was so successful and democratized booting so efficiently  that "these amateur power hungry low level developers" started moving into firmware lands themselves, with new project: coreboot. Radical no-nonsense no-bullshit open source BIOS replacement for IBM PC compatibles, that has potential to boot anything with speeds and simplicity unprecedented. In a corporate world a heresy.

You have to understand how much old of guard depends on obtuse booting and firmware environment of IBM PC world. There is whole industry of early boot software corporations providing early boot stuff, that would instantly evaporate or would be forced to deal with major disruption should coreboot efforts succeed with manufacturers.

More importantly it would be even easier to manufacture bootlegged rag-tag PCs based on completely open firmware components.

Sidenote: do you remember that almost all modern OSes are MULTIBOOT compliant? This is completely non-corporate grassroots achievement of ad-hoc OSDev tinkerers, which was possible to happen only on most free and most abundant most developer friendly platform on the Earth: legacy BIOS powered PC.

Imagine a parallel future, where PC would end up completely open platform running free firmware, free bootloaders and free OSes. We were heading straight into that future and such future would be very scary for many, many powers that be. Some CPU manufacturers even started eyeing that future (AMD) and are still doing steps in those directions, even today.

For some other corporate players this was not to pass. Situation like that would probably completely changed the PC game: both on OS and hardware sides, should hardware manufacturers jump on it (coreboot) en masse.

Situation like that would also make Apple style platform lockdown completely impossible. And it is whispered to these days in coporate quarters, that Apple style lockdown is only path to success in tech.

Situation had to be remedied immediately and unfortunately for users and fortunately for the corporations, chance has opened eventually: multiple CPUs and huge disk drives.

Original MS-DOS partitioning scheme was wearing thin as drives were moving into terabyte territories (original partition table size fields are too short to express length of new, over terabyte big, disk sizes), thus Intel with help from Microsoft proposed a new partitioning format know as GPT: an GUID Partition Table which is part of so called UEFI effort (extended successor of the original EFI effort). This partitioning table scheme (not exclusively) was used as an vehicle to pull-in change in whole status quo.

Thus we got UEFI, brainchild of so called Wintel (Intel + Microsoft) platform.

Nowadays when Solid State Drives are more common it is easier to understand UEFI - it is special-purpose Operating System installed on special solid state storage inside motherboard of every modern (circa post 2008) IBM PC compatible computer. It has great ambition to venture into mobile space as well. It is already supported on ARM based servers.

The rollout was very well coordinated and organized among all participants (from Intel through Microsoft and involved opensource community, down to computers and computer components manufacturers) and by the fact that in 202* 99.9999% of PCs manufactured since are UEFI based, proves, that it was utlimatively successful.

This effort, along side with introduction of TPM (Trusted Platform Module) and Intel ME (Intel Management Engine) under guise of protection (from themselves, so called "security") of users (ie. causuals) was biggest and most coordinated and most successful platform lockdown implemented in human history.

Unlike coreboot and other boot platforms, where authenticity and authority of both hardware and boot chain are tangential questions, question of authenticated booting is one of core question posed in UEFI specification (so called SecureBoot errata).

So what is UEFI?

UEFI is microscopic OS, comparable in complexity with Microsoft Windows 9x, from which it actually borrows many data formats, binary structures and design ideas (ie GUUID labelled interfaces, UEFI applications are specially crafted windows EXEs, etc).

UEFI is basically almost exact copy (in scope, but not in implementation!) of GRUB, only difference being that while GRUB is oriented towards the computer user, UEFI is geared towards the computer manufacturer.

For UEFI to succeed several things had to be achieved, one of those is it being an opensource project.

So actual canonical UEFI implementation (so called [Tiano Core/EDK](https://www.tianocore.org/)) is an opensource effort, that anyone can enter and develop and develop for. This defuses any criticism of it being closed or proprietary platform.

UEFI had to be at least as good as any free/libre or opensource alternative. This was achieved, because UEFI is an actual OS (or rather firmwaros) and it can run actual applications. Because it is supportive of proprietary hardware manufacturers (thanks to it's BSD license - which allows to create closed proprietary products, based on open source software) it has access to proprietary graphics stacks, thus it is bringing access to graphics for very early boot applications (and everybody likes pictures). All these factors make it very flexible and attractive deployment platform.

Finally, at the same time, it was imperative it is very friendly to corporate ecosystem that grew around boot environments and has many entrenched players ([AMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Megatrends) from AMIBIOS/Aptio fame, [Phoenix Technologoies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_Technologies), [InsydeH2O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insyde_Software) and others), and should also be allowing for complete platform lockdowns (for hardware systems manufacturers like Microsoft, Lenovo and others) - for which it has explicitly engineered interfaces.

Management of it is spearheaded these days by [UEFI Forum](https://uefi.org/) which is non-profit corporation having impressive [member list](https://uefi.org/members) (this defuses any argument UEFI is controlled solely by monopolistic entities (like Microsoft and Intel for example)).

During the past years many IP (Intellectual Ptoperty) assets, that were formerly in Intel's and Microsoft's ownership were transferred towards the Forum.

However unlike GRUB or normal OS, UEFI is not installed onto a computer's hard disk (although it can be compiled in MULTIBOOT form, see "everybody booting with everybody" section, and then installed onto normal hard disk like regular OS), but it is installed directly onto a computer's motherboard(!).

Thus 90% of every "BIOS" (or firmware rather) shipped to PC consumers these days is this open source UEFI "OS", which is providing all basic firmware services. Of course these 90% of services would be useless without combination of specific, manufacturer provided, proprietary drivers (actual spot where the motherboard firmware value is added).

UEFI simplified and corpo-democratised new computer motherboards and computers and notebook computer manufacture (further bringing the costs down): hardware providers do not have to write their own "bioses"/firmwares from scratch anymore. All they need is to base their firmware on Tiano Core and they immediately get a working platform.

They can take this well developed and well tested and open UEFI installation and complement it with their own additional special drivers, designed solely for their hardware. Once installed onto their motherboard, the end consumers will get familiar UEFI interfaces for free and thanks to UEFI support in all modern OSes (and should the manufacturer's additional drivers be well tested and work well), automatic support for the machine from all UEFI enabled OSes.

UEFI successfuly "attacks" all the crucial areas that were previously dominated by user deployed disk based bootmanagers and bootloaders (from "booter" era), that we discussed earlier:

- Network Booting - when extended with embedded network card drivers motherboards can PXE boot directly, without relying on SYSLINUX PXEBOOT feature.
- Boot Manager - because UEFI understands concepts of multiple bootloaders and can read GPT EFI partition and FAT32 filesystem directly, motherboard itself can have UEFI application installed, that can act as boot manager directly, without a need for separate Boot Manager program (this is exactly what f11/boot menu in modern firmwares basically is)
- Boot Loader - because UEFI understands concepts of multiple bootloaders and can read GPT EFI partition and FAT32 filesystem directly, motherboard itself can just directly boot into the target OS kernel, should this kernel also be an UEFI application (which stock Linux actually is(!) (and will hold true for many other OSes in future)).
- as UEFI is Windows 9x complexity level OS, it can run any UEFI compliant applications, opening up opportunity for motherboard manufacturers to bundle motherboards with various self-diagnostic, self-testing and self-benchmarking utilities, or any crapware really, which is trend already emerging in gaming PCs. Frankly only sky is a limit here, as you can embed anything into motherboard this way: an music player, kiosk internet browser, movie player or whatever one fancies.
- as UEFI actively solves question of authentication, manufacturers can lock down firmware updates only from authenticated sources thus, maintain "security" or preventing noconformant users from removing bundled crapware from the motherboard.
- because UEFI understands concepts of multiple bootloaders and can read GPT EFI partition and FAT32 filesystem directly, motherboard can run directly any application installed there by user: be it bootloader, operating system kernel, internet kiosk application, music player application, or anything really, sky is the limit here (*of course only under the condition, that whole motherboard is not locked down by it's manufacturer* **(!)** *, or application is blessed by manufacturer through cryptographic means (i.e. by SecureBoot signing)* **(!)**).

Final realization of this development is, that UEFI can boot your OS directly without any intermediary bootloaders whatsoever - which is also very attractive proposition for for example locked-down tablets, phones and TV manufacturers.

Because UEFI provides same abilities as GRUB and SYSLINUX, it is also welcomed as replacement for those, by part of end user community (of course this endorsement will last only as long as their UEFI installation remains unlocked by their respective motherboards manufacturers) capable of practically utilizing these features.

Philosophical question here is, whether this does not give manufacturers incentives to proliferate their products unlocked first to gain market advantage, and then to lock them all in final sweep, to sanitize the ecosystem with only vetted applications later, artificially re-pivoting their markets and leveraging their market positions.

In this new environment, unless they bring some actual advantage to bear (like rescue CDs and such) GRUB, SYSLINUX and many other bootloaders, are quickly becoming superfluous and irrelevant piece of software, because more intermediate booting steps you can remove, the faster the machine will boot (especially for static (tablet, notebook, workstation, server), single OS installations).

Modern in-VM TianoCore based UEFI implementations paired with proper hypervisor (like combination of Linux [KVM](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) + [OVFM](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/OVMF)) can, with specific tuning, boot and reboot virtual machines in subsecond times.

Combined with advanced system supervision techniques (highly tuned systemd, runit, nosh, s6 inits) such virtualized instalaltions can reboot to full working state in subsecond times, feature important in both on-premise clouds and internet cloud environments.

UEFI capable "bootloaders":

- almost all "booter" loaders still alive can be chained into form UEFI
- [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) - advanced, graphical, skinnable, multiboot, UEFI only bootmanager/loader
- [UEFI Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#UEFI_shell) - standalone "shell" command line application in scope roughly comparable to MS-DOS command line interpreter COMMAN.COM - you can inspect UEFI view of "storage layer" (disks and FAT32 volumes on them, if readable (if your UEFI has drivers for different filesystems i.e. Apple, you can inspect those too)), load UEFI drivers etc. and most importantly you can launch any other UEFI applications from it
- many others - as UEFI application development is much simpler (compared to BIOS), as before your "applications" had to be respective SYSLINUX, GRUB, XOSL plug-in modules, and with UEFI you are given complete UEFI "OS" with EDK, expect many more tools to come...

---

**Situation on other platforms**

Whoa! You successfully reached the end of this answer, but plaform you asked for was not IBM PC based. Bummer.

No problem: imagine article exactly of the same length, but with different actors and within different timeframes - often historically sooner (OpenBoot, OpenFirmware, OpenBIOS), sometimes later (U-Boot on ARM based platforms for example).

---

**Conslusion**

Now you should see pretty clearly that your question makes no sense, and we got to first generic answer:

***Only firmware is the first program ever run and that's it!***

Answer (score 0):

Boot Manager I suppose. Apparently in the case of UEFI, boot manager is somewhat equivalent to a program where you can choose which EFI executable to execute, while bootloader would be one of the EFI executables available. (But the boot manager itself would also be an EFI executable and it can chainload another boot manager as well.)

Or you can see it this way, a boot manager allows you to choose either a bootloader or another boot manager to execute, while a bootloader is always for loading an OS/kernel, except when the bootloader is not just a bootloader but a "dual-role" program like grub.

Like in terms of grub's `linux` and `initrd` command, it's a bootloader. But it is also a boot manager given the `chainloader` command.

Note that in the case of systemd-boot, it is a boot manager instead of a bootloader, since it doesn't boot Linux in the same way as grub does. The EFISTUB in the kernel image is the actual bootloader (which is not used by grub's `linux` command).

P.S. I'm not sure if anyone is at the place to define what a boot manager is. Either way, it seems that there's also a more general definition that boot manager is a bootloader that allows a choice of OS / installation to boot. So grub might be considered a bootloader and a boot manager even if it does not have the `chainloader` command, but just because one set of grub can serve multiple Linux installations.

As you may have realized, boot manager is not something that is crucial. The computer (BIOS or whatever on those ARM boards) can load a bootloader directly and that bootloader can be one that always loads one same OS installation / kernel, which explains your linked article. (In the case of UEFI, the firmware comes with a built-in boot manager that is AFAIK always used, so one may argue a boot manager is crucial in this case.)

Btw, I wonder if the term "boot manager" was a thing / defined at all in the era of BIOS.